# Solving system of congruences where $m$'s are not coprime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

I'm really struggling with how to find the solution to a system of congruences where the m_i's are not relatively prime. For example:

$x ≡ 3 (mod4)$

$x ≡ 1 (mod6)$.

I know this has a unique solution mod 12 but I'm stuck here. I read through some similar questions but I'm still confused. Since I can't use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, how do I find the solution?

Comment: The second one can be replaced by $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3.$ In general, and not the quickest method, any one of these can be separated into statements modulo prime powers. If the results are consistent, as they are here, you get answers.

Answer (score 2):

Write $$4k+3 =x=6l+1$$ so we have
$$2k+1=3l \Longrightarrow 2\mid 3l-1 \Longrightarrow 2\mid l-1 \Longrightarrow l-1=2n$$
Thus $l=2n+1$ and $k=3n+1$ and finally $x= 12n+7$. Or if you want $x\equiv 7 \pmod {12}$.

Comment: How did you get from $2 | 3l-1$ to $2 | l-1$ ?

Comment: 2|3 -1 means 3-1 is even. Subtracting even from even gives even, so 3 - 1 - 2(which is even) =  - 1, which implies 2 |  - 1.

Answer (score 2):

You use the CRT for each modulus, then combine the results.  For your system,
$x \cong 3 \pmod{4}$ just gives you that congruence (because $4$ is a power of a prime) and then $x \cong 1 \pmod{6}$ gives \begin{align*}
    x &\cong 1 \pmod{2}  \\
    x &\cong 1 \pmod{3}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

The first of these is redundant with the previous equation ("$x$ is odd" is compatible with but tells you less than $x \cong 3 \pmod{4}$.)  So your *three* equations reduce to \begin{align*}
    x &\cong 3 \pmod{4}  \\
    x &\cong 1 \pmod{3}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Then reassemble using the CRT: $x \cong 7 \pmod{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

For small values, like your problem, you can use the method of adding the modulus:

$\pmod{6}: x\equiv 1\equiv 7 $.

Then noting that also $7\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, you have your solution:

$x\equiv 7 \pmod{12}$

(Sometimes you may have to add the modulus more than once.)